# deb package has no usr/lib after installation

Tags: bash, package-management, dpkg, deb, lintian

I'm building a simple single binary deb package, everything works fine with the executable that is placed in the usr/bin folder and executes when I click the desktop icon. 
Now I want to start programming the functionalities, so I write the bash scripts and normaly the packagebuilder add's them to the usr/lib folder after adding them to the debian/install file.

But my deb package has no usr/lib folder after installation, I can add them to the usr/bin folder, but lintian requires a manpage for every file in the bin folder so that's not really an option.

How do I get the usr/lib folder? Lintian never complains when the package is beeing build so I dont know where I should put this.

Regards 
Gijs

Comment: silly question, but did you set the right path in the .install file?

Comment: Lintian requires a lot of things. I occasionally consider taking lintian out to the backyard and shooting it when building a package for local use.

Comment: ...but with or without lintian, it is ugly to store them in `/usr/bin`, and I am not sure the package is for "home" use only.

Comment: @JacobVlijm, not a silly question. Made a silly typo in my install file. It's a school assignment so not home use but also not made for distribution. Now the usr/lib folder is created at installation. Searched for a day after that fault. Thank you

Comment: perfect! would you mind if I made it an answer? That way it will not appear anymore as "unanswered".

Comment: @JacobVlijm, no problem, go ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installation directories should be defined in the `debian/[applicationname].install` file. Check if you set the correct path (`/usr/lib`) for your scripts and it should work.